# DevTools Opens CSS in a new Tab Instead of Opening up Sources Panel

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to follow along the Discover DevTools course over at CodeSchool.

When I click on the link to the CSS file, I expect DevTools to open it up in the Sources Panel. Instead, Chrome just opens up the CSS file in a new tab.

[image: Screenshot of CSS location]

Not sure what I broke.

I'm running Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 on OS X 10.8.4

Comment: Any chance you can try Beta/Dev/Canary channel?

Comment: Canary seems to work. It's not a bleeding-edge feature though?

Comment: It is not. But from the screenshot, it looks like something has gone bad with the resource loading by DevTools. Does it reproduce consistently for you?